# Outlook Desktop Year Selector

Tags: date, drop-down-menu, outlook

Is there anyway to quickly switch between years within the **Microsoft Outlook Calendar**? I'd love if there was an easy drop down selector box (Drop Down Menu). Has anyone build a macro or add-in for this kind of functionality?

The easiest way I've found so far is to use the Go To Date function, but I'm lazy and don't want to type.

[image: GoToDate]

I'm looking at then **Outlook Desktop Office** app, not the online *Outlook.com* version.

Comment: Ask non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a macro where you can customize the [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212(v=office.15).aspx) property (see the Explorer and Folder classes). Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

Also you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article helpful.